# how to show "*" Character in input filed in Django

Tags: python, django, dojo

I am beginner in python and django. I have created a form in Django Framework .I have created one password field. I want "*" (symbol)character in that password field.

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from freenasUI.freeadmin.models import Model
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from freenasUI.contrib.IPAddressField import (IPAddressField, IP4AddressField,IP6AddressField)
import utils

class VcenterConfiguration(Model):

ip_choices = utils.get_management_ips()

vc_management_ip = models.CharField(
    max_length = 120,
    verbose_name = _(" TrueNAS Management IP Address"),
    choices=zip(ip_choices,ip_choices), default='1',
    help_text = 'test run.',
    )

vc_username = models.CharField(
    max_length = 120,
    verbose_name = _(" vCenter User name"),
    )

vc_password = models.CharField(
    blank = True,
    null = True,
    max_length = 120,
    verbose_name = _(" vCenter Password"),
    )



class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("VCenter Configuration")
    verbose_name_plural = _("VCenter Configuration")

class FreeAdmin:
    icon_model = 'VsphereIcon'
    icon_object = 'VsphereIcon'
    icon_view = 'VsphereIcon'
    icon_add = 'VsphereIcon'
```

How should i show "*" Symbol in password field ?
Thanx in adavance

Comment: This isn't anything to do with django but html, Or at the very least django forms. Either way the code you've provided isn't anything to do with how you *show* the template, which is where the problem lies

Comment: In your model's field: [`widget = PasswordInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#passwordinput)

Answer (score 1):

If you writing a form in template by hands (its not so good), so you can just type:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="password" name="pass"> 
</form>
```

but if you render form like this {{form}} , you need to change your form to

```
from django.forms import CharField, Form, PasswordInput

class UserForm(Form):
    password = CharField(widget=PasswordInput())
```